# How can I update two User objects in the same Rails form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I'm trying to use a form_for in rails to update two objects from the User model at the same time. The reason is that a person can update basic information for both themselves and their spouse (two different users), without having to fill out two separate forms.

My current code for updating one user looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url=> wizard_path, :method => :put) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group form-question-group">
        <%= f.label :state, "What state do you live in?", class: "form-question" %>
        <%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, selected: @user.state), {:prompt => "State"}, :class => "form-control", :required => true) %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= link_to "Back", previous_wizard_path, :class => "align-left" %>
        <%= f.submit "Continue", :class => "btn btn-primary align-right" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I edit this form so that on submit it updates not just the current user, but also the user's spouse (which can be accessed by @user.spouse).

Comment: Does this form handles only users(husbands) that could have spouses ?, doesn't it also handle users(spouses) that could have husbands ?. You could use nested attributes(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your models, and fields_for https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my idea is using your user controller update method

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    # here you update spouse
    spouse = @user.spouse
    if spouse.present?
      spouse.state = @user.state
      spouse.save
    end
    flash[:success] = 'success'
  end
end
```

Comment: Vote it, but just one thing is, I would wrap two updates into an ActiveRecord::Base.transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the classic use case for [ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records
>   through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off
>   and you can enable it using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` class
>   method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is
>   defined on the model.

```
class User
  belongs_to :spouse
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :spouse
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url=> wizard_path, :method => :put) do |f| %>
  # ...
  <%= f.fields_for :spouse do |sf| %>
     <%= sf.label :name, 'Your spouses name' %>
     <%= sf.text_field :name %>
  <% end %
<% end %>
```

---

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
        .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz, spouse_attributes: [:id, :name, :email]) # ...
end
```

Since this is handled on the model layer you don't have to do anything in your controller besides whitelisting the nested attributes.